# Teradata sum non unique records

Tags: sql, teradata

Here are the 3 separate tables with data.

Table Adj_Orig

```
ID LINE_NUM  DOLLAR_AMT
12  3           $3.41
```

Table Adj_Reversal

```
ID LINE_NUM  DOLLAR_AMT
12  3           ($3.41)
```

Table Adj_Retro

```
ID LINE_NUM  DOLLAR_AMT
12  3           $0.00  
12  3           $1.90  
12  3           $1.42  
12  3           $0.09
```

The following sql gives me the results below.

```
    SELECT orig.ID AS ID1,
    orig.LINE_NUM AS ID1_LINE,
    reversal.ID AS ID2,
    reversal.LINE_NUM AS ID2_LINE,
    retro.ID AS ID3,
    retro.LINE_NUM AS ID3_LINE
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    FROM schema.Adj_Orig orig                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    LEFT OUTER JOIN schema.Adj_Reversal reversal ON (reversal.ID = orig.ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    AND reversal.LINE_NUM = orig.LINE_NUM)
 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN schema.Adj_retro ON (retro.ID = orig.ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    AND retro.LINE_NUM = orig.LINE_NUM)
   
    WHERE orig.ID = '12'
```

```
ID1 ID1_LINE ID2  ID2_LINE ID3 ID3_LINE ORIG_AMT REVERSAL_AMT RETRO_AMT
12  3        12   3        12  3           $3.41      ($3.41)     $0.00 
12  3        12   3        12  3           $3.41      ($3.41)     $1.90 
12  3        12   3        12  3           $3.41      ($3.41)     $1.42 
12  3        12   3        12  3           $3.41      ($3.41)     $0.09
```

I have this sql with sum functions giving the me the results below.

```
SELECT
orig.ID AS ID1,
orig.LINE_NUM AS ID1_LINE,
reversal.ID AS ID2,
reversal.LINE_NUM AS ID2_LINE,
retro.ID AS ID3,
retro.LINE_NUM AS ID3_LINE,
SUM(orig.DOLLAR_AMT) AS ORIG_AMT,
SUM(reversal.DOLLAR_AMT) AS REVERSAL_AMT,
SUM(retro.DOLLAR_AMT) AS RETRO_AMT   -- Ok
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
FROM schema.Adj_Orig orig                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
LEFT OUTER JOIN schema.Adj_Reversal reversal ON (reversal.ID = orig.ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
AND reversal.LINE_NUM = orig.LINE_NUM)

LEFT OUTER JOIN schema.Adj_retro ON (retro.ID = orig.ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
AND retro.LINE_NUM = orig.LINE_NUM)

WHERE orig.ID = '12'

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6

;


ID1 ID1_LINE ID2  ID2_LINE ID3 ID3_LINE ORIG_AMT REVERSAL_AMT RETRO_AMT
12  3        12   3        12  3          $13.64     ($13.64)     $3.41
```

I need the sql to give me the following results.

```
ID1 ID1_LINE ID2  ID2_LINE ID3 ID3_LINE ORIG_AMT REVERSAL_AMT RETRO_AMT
12  3        12   3        12  3           $3.41      ($3.41)     $3.41
```

How do I get the ORIG_AMT & REVERSAL_AMT to only count the 3.41 value once.

Thansk!

I tried `OVER (PARTITION BY)`, but it is giving me the same value.

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Your query involves three tables, but you have only provided sample data for one of them - which one? And give us sample data for the other two as well. (All matching the expected result.)

Comment: You edited the question and the only change you made was to make it unreadable once again. Can you edit and revert, or change your table data to use proper [markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/438222).

Comment: The simplest solution (at least to me) is that you need to get all your tables to the same grain. Based on your sample data, use a derived table to aggregate Adj_Retro so you get one row per id and line_num.

Comment: Based on your data switching to `MAX(orig.DOLLAR_AMT) AS ORIG_AMT,
MAX(reversal.DOLLAR_AMT) AS REVERSAL_AMT` should work. Or aggregate `Adj_Retro` before the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `SUM()` from `orig_amt` and `reversal_amt` columns:

```
SELECT
orig.ID AS ID1,
orig.LINE_NUM AS ID1_LINE,
reversal.ID AS ID2,
reversal.LINE_NUM AS ID2_LINE,
retro.ID AS ID3,
retro.LINE_NUM AS ID3_LINE,
orig.DOLLAR_AMT AS ORIG_AMT,
reversal.DOLLAR_AMT AS REVERSAL_AMT,
SUM(retro.DOLLAR_AMT) AS RETRO_AMT   -- Ok
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
FROM schema.Adj_Orig orig                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
LEFT OUTER JOIN schema.Adj_Reversal reversal ON (reversal.ID = orig.ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
AND reversal.LINE_NUM = orig.LINE_NUM)

LEFT OUTER JOIN schema.Adj_retro ON (retro.ID = orig.ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
AND retro.LINE_NUM = orig.LINE_NUM)

WHERE orig.ID = '12'

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

To your comment: just toss this in a subquery and sum once again:

```
SELECT ID1, ID1_LINE, ID2, ID2_LINE, ID3, ID3_LINE, SUM(ORIG_AMT) as ORIG_AMT, SUM(REVERSAL_AMT) as REVERSAL_AMT, SUM(RETRO_AMT) as RETRO_AMT
FROM
(
  SELECT
    orig.ID AS ID1,
    orig.LINE_NUM AS ID1_LINE,
    reversal.ID AS ID2,
    reversal.LINE_NUM AS ID2_LINE,
    retro.ID AS ID3,
    retro.LINE_NUM AS ID3_LINE,
    orig.DOLLAR_AMT AS ORIG_AMT,
    reversal.DOLLAR_AMT AS REVERSAL_AMT,
    SUM(retro.DOLLAR_AMT) AS RETRO_AMT   -- Ok
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  FROM schema.Adj_Orig orig                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    LEFT OUTER JOIN schema.Adj_Reversal reversal ON (reversal.ID = orig.ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      AND reversal.LINE_NUM = orig.LINE_NUM)

    LEFT OUTER JOIN schema.Adj_retro ON (retro.ID = orig.ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      AND retro.LINE_NUM = orig.LINE_NUM)

  WHERE orig.ID = '12'

  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
) dt
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: I need to open this query up to more than just ID 12.

Comment: I don't see how that affects the answer. Remove the WHERE clause and let 'er rip.

Comment: When I open it up, I need to sum the ORIG_AMT & REVERSAL_AMT.

Comment: Gotcha. Just a sec.

Comment: I got to work with your suggestion.  Thanks!